# Does the double split experiment set boundaries to the concept of localization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment, interference

Feynman's textbook on quantum mechanics starts with the double split experiment for single electrons, see chapter 1-5. The astonishing result is the self-interference of the single electron as long as it is not observed on its way from source to detector.

Are interference and localization complementary properties in this experiment? I.e. either we prepare a state of interference or - by observation - we prepare a state of localization?